# Closing a current form to open another using a DataGridView click event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a data grid view that opens a form to display student details when the row header is clicked. I would like to click the row header again to open up another form while closing the previous form. This is easy with a button exit but can not make it work by clicking  on the data grid view row header. I hope I explained this correctly. Thanks !
Here is my code to open a form.

```
    private void dgvViewStudents_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender,                                                 DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) // click on dgv row
    {           
        int index = dgvViewStudents.CurrentRow.Index;
        DataRow drCurrent = dtViewStud.Rows[index];
        string StudentID = drCurrent[1].ToString();
        ViewStudentDet frm = new ViewStudentDet(StudentID);
        frm.Show(); // passes data to ViewStudentForm                       
    }
```

Comment: you can not close as new instance will be running on current instance. So you can hide it by this.Hide();

Comment: would you prefer to open it as a dialog?

Comment: this.Hide would work if I could call the click event again but everything I try does not work. I did try the show dialog but again no luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here's what you gonna do. let's asume you have 2 forms to show when click on header 
create instance of those 2 forms as class variables.

```
ViewStudentDet1 frm1;
ViewStudentDet2 frm2;
```

also a switch to move with click.. cus you are clicking same header and need a variable to switch between your conditions

in the constructor initialize them

```
frm1 = new ViewStudentDet1();
frm2 = new ViewStudentDet2();
```

also create a public variable inside those forms accepting "StudentID"

first time clicked
you just activate and show or showdialog it

```
if(swich ==//your condition){
  if(form2 is in Application.OpenForms collection){
     form2.hide();
  }
frm1.StudentID = //give an id
frm1.Activate()
frm1.DOSomething();
frm1.show()
}else{
 if(form1 is in Application.OpenForms collection){
     form1.hide();
  }
frm2.StudentID = //give an id
frm2.Activate()
frm2.DOSomething();
frm2.show()
}
```

Comment: Thanks H-a-Neo, Ill give it a go !